# Printing a matrix with the same amount of characters per element in C

Tags: c, matrix, printing, character, spaces

I have this code to print a matrix:

```
void imprimir_matriz (double matriz[][3]){
    for (unsigned short int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (unsigned short int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            printf ("|%lf", matriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("|\n");
    }
}
```

But as output I am getting this:

```
|0.8000000|-0.6000000|-2.8000000|
|-0.6000000|0.2000000|0.6000000|
|-0.2000000|0.4000000|12.2000000|
```

But what I really want is for the elements to be like "aligned", like this:

```
| 0.8000000  | -0.6000000 | -2.8000000 |
| -0.6000000 | 0.2000000  | 0.6000000  |
| -0.2000000 | 0.4000000  | 12.2000000 |
```

And it is not just a matter of adding extra spaces, as the amount of digits of the integer part of the number may vary.
Please, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the width and precision in the format string like this: "% 6.2lf" which reserves space for 6 characters and rounds the number to 2 decimal places and the space means "*even if there's no sign put space there*". [source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/#parameters)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a quick and dirty solution, that would be to add `\t` characters after the numbers, and base that on your largest number.

If you really want it to be dynamic you can do the following

You could also count the number of digits in your largest number, by first going through the matrix and finding the largest number, counting the digits it has, and basing your spacing on that.

To count the number of digits you can use something like;

```
while (n != 0) {
    n /= 10;
    ++count;
}
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: It's a double though, that makes it a lot more difficult to count the number of digits.

Comment: Yep, it helped, but I really need it to be dynamic and I knew there were specifiers for that, but didn't know how to use them. Thanks anyway!